# weird error from pandas.read_csv on zipped csv file from URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, zip

I've seen similar questions posted but they're not exactly the same as what I've encountered. I am using Python 3.7 and Pandas 0.25.0.

Weirdly, if I download this zip file directly from [this link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/6649/publicleaderboarddata.zip), I am able to read it via `pd.read_csv` as follows:

```
pd.read_csv('publicleaderboarddata.zip')
       TeamId           TeamName       SubmissionDate    Score
0      688191  Sergey Mushinskiy  2017-05-24 12:20:34  0.06630
1      688203       DeepVoltaire  2017-05-24 12:25:03  0.06630
2      688237        RakeshNikam  2017-05-24 13:02:31  0.06512
......
```

However, if I do:

```
this_leaderboard_df = pd.read_csv('https://www.kaggle.com/c/6649/publicleaderboarddata.zip,
                                  compression='zip')
```

I will get a `BadZipFile`error as follows. Why does this happen?

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 this_leaderboard_df = pd.read_csv(this_leaderboard_link, compression='zip')
>         2 this_leaderboard_df.head(e)
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col,
>   usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters,
>   true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter,
>   nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
>   skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
>   date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression,
>   thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote,
>   escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines,
>   warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map,
>   float_precision)
>       683         )
>       684 
>   --> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       686 
>       687     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       455 
>       456     # Create the parser.
>   --> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
>       458 
>       459     if chunksize or iterator:
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   **init**(self, f, engine, **kwds)
>       893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
>       894 
>   --> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
>       896 
>       897     def close(self):
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   _make_engine(self, engine)    1133     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):    1134         if engine == "c":
>   -> 1135             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)    1136         else:    1137             if engine == "python":
>
> ~/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in
>   **init**(self, src, **kwds)    1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols    1916 
>   -> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)    1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols    1919
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py
>   in **init**(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel) 
>   1223         try:    1224             if mode == 'r':
>   -> 1225                 self._RealGetContents()    1226             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):    1227                 # set the modified
>   flag so central directory gets written
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py
>   in _RealGetContents(self)    1290             raise BadZipFile("File
>   is not a zip file")    1291         if not endrec:
>   -> 1292             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")    1293         if self.debug > 1:    1294             print(endrec)
>
> BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: to download it you have to login to kaggle. Logout from kaggle and then try to download directly from link to see login form. `pandas` can't login to this page so it gets HTML pages with login form instead of zip file.

Comment: @furas ah yes this is the answer to my error. thanks!

Comment: you could use `Selenium` to control web browser and login to kaggle and click on link to download file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download it you have to be logged in to Kaggle. If you logout from Kaggle and try to download directly from link then you see login form.

`pandas` can't login to this page so it gets HTML with login form instead of zip file.

You could use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser and then script can use browser to login to Kaggle and to download file.